# New shy cat put paws on my legs, what could that mean?

Tags: cats, behavior

I just adopted a cat and he just came from behind the stove after a week.  He only comes out when humans are gone.  Over the last few days, he's built up some trust for me and I pet him and he paces around me in a circle  (that's part of the question  too).

Just now he put his front paws on my legs, the nails are a bit long, what is this behavior  saying?  I'm use to it with dogs, but not cats. I've never owed a cat.

Comment: When you say he put his paws on your legs, did he claw at your? Or did he simply just rest his paws on your leg?

Comment: I wouldn't say it was a claw it wasn't a quick motion it was like he placed them there and wanted to go down my leg.  He

Answer (score 10):

It sounds like your cat is getting to know you and is slowly developing a trusting relationship!  He's in a new place with lots of new smells and things to explore, so it may take a few weeks before he feels "normal" and comfortable in your space.

As for the pacing - this sounds like normal curious cat behavior when they're starting to accept you.  You'll know you're accepted if he rubs against you. *Please note if a cat is walking in circles but seems to be stumbling or disoriented, this is very different and it needs to be brought to a vet*

The paws on the leg sound like a friendly hi and perhaps a request for something.  He could be asking to be petted, or needs food/water, or wants a treat.

Reward any trust behavior with treats, and talk to him in a soothing tone.  Try to move slower when you're around him, and don't make sudden moves or noises. You could try coaxing him to play if you've got any toys.  Playing is a great bonding activity.  Good luck! It sounds like you're on your way to having a new best friend!